# Submit HTML form in a new tab

Tags: html, forms

For testing, I'd like to load the page called by submit on a new tab. Is this possible?

Answer (score 428, accepted):

```
<form target="_blank" [....]
```

will submit the form in a new tab... I am not sure if is this what you are looking for, please explain better...

Comment: the `jquery` tag confused me, i thought you were talking about an ajax request ;)

Comment: @nalply: Seriously? Most browsers DO use tabs everytime a website suggests them to use a new window (`target="_blank"`). And that's a good thing because pretty much nobody wants a website to open a new window and I don't think this default will ever change since pretty much every website uses `_blank` nowadays.

Comment: That's sweeping an important detail under the rug. `_blank` does not open a new tab. It is opening a new **window**, which mostly (but not always!!) default to opening a new **tab**. It depends on the configuration of the browser. Please see this **heavily** upvoted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/220060

Comment: @nalply I can agree with you that that command open the link in a new *window*, but you have to agree with me that all the known browser today open new windows as *tabs*, so the result is the same.
If the user configured the browser manually to open a new window, then is a choose *he did* and we can't do nothing to prevent this.

Comment: @Strae, okay, it's slowly dawning on me. I use tabs for years but I still thought that non-power users didn't yet discover tabs.

Comment: Technically youre right, but nowadays the only pages that i see to open as a window and not as a tab are ads

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya why not?

Comment: This no longer works in Chome version 83+ - perhaps formtarget="_blank" on the button will work instead.

Answer (score 54):

It is also possible to use the new button attribute called `formtarget` that was introduced with HTML5.

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" formtarget="_blank"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It also works with the <button> tag when it is of type submit.

Answer (score 28):

I have a [submit] and a [preview] button,
I want the preview to show the print view of the submitted form data, without persisting it to database. Therefore I want [preview] to open in a new tab, and submit to submit the data in the same window/tab.

```
<button type="submit" id="liquidacion_save"          name="liquidacion[save]"          onclick="$('form').attr('target', '');"      >Save</button></div>    <div>
<button type="submit" id="liquidacion_Previsualizar" name="liquidacion[Previsualizar]" onclick="$('form').attr('target', '_blank');">Preview</button></div>
```

Answer (score 18):

Add `target="_blank"` to the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 9):

Since you've got this tagged jQuery, I'll assume you want something to stick in your success function?

```
success: function(data){
    window.open('http://www.mysite.com/', '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("form").submit(function() {
$("form").attr('target', '_blank');
return true;
});
</script>
```

Here is a full answer - http://ftutorials.com/open-html-form-in-new-tab/

Answer (score 4):

This will also work great, u can do something else while a new tab handler the submit .

```
<form target="_blank">
    <a href="#">Submit</a>
</form>

<script>
    $('a').click(function () {
        // do something you want ...

        $('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your browser options must be set to open new windows in a new tab, otherwise a new browser window is opened.