# Form Submission Opens New Tab/Window?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [submit a form in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709590/submit-a-form-in-a-new-tab)

How can i open a new window when i submit one form?

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
    First Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="Fname">:<br />
    Last Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="36" name="Lname">:<br />
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 37):

you can use code like this

```
    <form action="#" method="post" target="_blank">
      ...
    </form>
```