# In html how to link form submit to open in new tab and link relative URL?

Tags: html, forms, submit

I'm trying to link the submit button to open my URL in a new tab but at best I've managed to open an error window. Is the form action the correct way? Thanks

```
<div class="container">
      <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    ***<form action="_blank><a href="Home.html"></a>***
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not appropriately using the `action` attribute. You have to use `_blank` in the `target` attribute and then specify where to send the form-data when the form is submitted in the `action` attribute. Read more about [HTML Form Attributes here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms_attributes.asp).

Your code should look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
      <h3>Contact Form</h3>
      <form target="_blank" action="/receiveFormData.html"><a href="Home.html"></a>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button title="button title" class="action primary tocart" onclick=" window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank'); return false;">Google</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question was already answered by Eric, here I'm just reproducing the same HTML code in the question to be easier to understand

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Contact Form</h3>
  <form target="_blank" action="Home.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, the question has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709590/submit-a-form-in-a-new-tab)