# my code is echoing the variable on same page of my webserver . Want the echo to be on next page without adding extra php

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and HTML.
My PHP file:

```php
<?php
include 'tele.html';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $environ = $_POST["environ"];
    if (!empty($environ)) {
            $command = "/scripts/telemetry/pod-node.sh " . escapeshellcmd($environ);
            $output = shell_exec($command);
             $plotlyHtml = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/Telemetry/pod_schedule.html');
             echo $plotlyHtml;
            exit();
    }
}
?>
```

My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IAM-LAB-Telemetry</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .navbar {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }
        .navbar a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .navbar a:hover {
            background-color: #04AA6D;
            color: black;
        }
        .footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 7px
        }
        .navbar .about-link {
            float: right;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/About" class="about-link">About</a>
    </div>
        <h2>Generate Charts for POD-NODE-Scheduler</h2>
        <form action="/Telemetry" method="post">
            <label for="environ">Select Environment:</label>
            <select name="environ" id="environ">
                <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
                <option value="yyy">yyy</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="generate-graph">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>BLAH BLAHH.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output of `echo $plotlyHtml` is shown in same page where I have the click "generate-graph".
I want that when I click on "generate-graph" button I should be redirected to another page and my output of `echo $plotlyHtml` should be shown in new page.

Comment: I'm guessing that the HTML represents the page at `/Telemetry`, is that right? If so, create a new page such as `/Telemetry-Graph`, put your PHP there, and change the form's action to point to that instead.

Comment: Yes , the /Telemetry is represented by tele.html and its inside /var/www/html/Telemetry
my file structure is as follows:
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 www-data www-data 3478175 Dec  7 10:03 plotly.js
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 www-data www-data     469 Dec  7 12:21 tele.php
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 www-data www-data    2312 Dec  7 12:22 tele.html
in that case it will aslo give me same issue . My php and html are working as desired , but the point is the output is rendered in same page where i click the button  and i want the output to be rendered ina new page

Comment: When you say "new page", do you mean "new URL", or do you mean "don't show the other stuff". If the latter, then just don't call `include 'tele.html';` if you detect the POST.

Comment: If i dont include the 'tele.html' then the button page donot appear.

Comment: Only include it when you want it to appear, possibly in an `else` to your existing `if`

Comment: I need it as when i click it it executes the php which executes the shell script which inturns executes the python script that generate the /var/www/html/Telemetry/pod_schedule.html . My point is i just want the echo $plotly.html in a different page .CUrrently when i click on the button the out is displayed on same page

Comment: Back to my prior question, what does "new page" mean? A new window or tab? Something else? Please elaborate on that.

Comment: Oh Chris, now i understand what you are asking.my bad.
a new Window will be good, Thanks

Comment: In that case, you can just set the target on the form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709607/231316

Comment: I tried using the 
but it still same,what it did is went to blank page and returned back to Telemetry and output was sown there

Comment: Make it post back to a different url which runs another script, which does something different. You can do that easily by changing the url in the action of the form

Comment: i used session start and redirected it to another page its solved my issue 
           if ($plotlypodHtml !== false) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['plotlypodHtml'] = $plotlypodHtml;
                header("Location: /Telemetry/pod-resource/display_poresourcegraph.php");
                exit();